# Why viewWillAppear is not call while present the other ViewController as a FormSheet

Tags: ios

I have 2 VC, A and B, when A present B as a FormSheet type, the method `viewWillDisappear` in A not called. So when I do something in B, and press back to A, the `ViewWillAppear` not called. So how to make the `viewWillAppear` in A called? I've seen somewhere, but I din't find the clearly answer.

In B I set:

```
protocol CallBackViewWillAppearDelegate: class {
    func callBackViewWillAppear(controller: UserRightRoleTableViewController)
}
```

and delegate variable:

```
weak var callBackViewWillAppearDelegate: CallBackViewWillAppearDelegate?
```

and in the back button:

```
@IBAction func backToUserRightButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        callBackViewWillAppearDelegate?.callBackViewWillAppear(self)
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)         
    }
```

In A I import the protocol and set the protocol function:

```
func callBackViewWillAppear(controller: UserRightRoleTableViewController) {
        viewWillAppear(true)
    }
```

Comment: Don't call `viewWillAppear` method from `callBackViewWillAppear` directly. Otherwise your app will call `super.viewWillAppear` method more than once.

Comment: No, because I forgot to set the value for callbackViewWillAppearDelegate :). When I set, it work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It not run, because I forgot to add this line in A Controller:

```
// b is a object of B ViewController

b.callBackViewWillAppearDelegate = self
```

It work now.

Answer (score 0):

The method `viewWillDisappear` is not called for A controller because this stays on the view hierarchy.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but as the question I ask, how to handle this case. But anyway, I've already fixed it now. Thanks